# Chrome remembers scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, scroll, viewport

I'm running into a problem that's actually a "feature" on Chrome.
As most of you might know, Chrome remembers a scroll position that it returns to, whenever you come back to a page. And I kind of have a problem with that.

Is there any way to override this without the user noticing?

Mees

**Failed try-outs:**

- ScrollTop on document.ready

Comment: what was your implementation of `.scrollTop(0)`? because i use it all the time with `popstate` events and it works perfectly.

Comment: I am using `$('body,html').scrollTop(0);` to scroll. After a ready.

Comment: just do `$('body').scrollTop(0)` (no `html`), and if it still doesn't work, make it run on `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: I noticed something. The method *does* work, but only if you close the tab and open it up again. It doesn't work when refreshing the page, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've checked on chrome, it worked well. Sometimes `setTimeout` does trick :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        scrollTo(0,-1);
    },0);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This works, but as soon as you start scrolling again, the page jumps to the memorized position

Comment: I think you missed setting the "milliseconds" value? As your snippet is set to 0 it will just run instantly. Set the "milliseconds" timeout value to 1000 and this solution works for me in Chrome.

Comment: actually, setting a timeout to 0 does not make the function run instantly--instead it adds the function to the end of the current execution queue (the code that scrolls to the remembered position would be in this queue)

Comment: the answer lower down for modifying `scrollRestoration` is the better one for modern browsers

Answer (score 75):

In Chrome 46+, the auto scroll behavior can be turned off using history.scrollRestoration:

```
if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
  history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
}
```

source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/history-api-scroll-restoration

Comment: This helped immensely! Great flag to know. Thanks!

Comment: This answer needs more appreciation! GJ Cory and thank you.

Comment: This also works in Firefox as of 2017. Definitely the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 0;  //horizontal coord
y = document.height; //vertical coord
window.scroll(x,y);
```

Some Javascript like that may very well be able to be manipulated to stop the auto scrolling.

It depends though, are you happy for the scroll to be simply set to automatically go to the top, or are you actually looking for the Chrome standard option to take the page to last scroll position, to be turned off completely?

What are you currently attempting to use for scrollTop()?

Comment: I'm afraid that code didn't work either. Chrome seems to ignore it and still goes back to its previous scroll position.
I'm using scrollTop(value) to scroll to a certain amount of pixels from the top of the viewport.

Comment: @MeesBoeijen - Maybe because Chrome scrolls back up after your scripts has finished executing. Try `setTimeout(func, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by attaching to scroll event, and then resetting scroll position the first time a user scrolls. Works for on-spot reloads for me.

Looks like this:

```
var scrollResetOnce = false;
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if (scrollResetOnce) return;
    scrollResetOnce = true;
    scrollTo(0, -1);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a clean way of getting this done.

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(e){
   document.body.style.display = 'none';
});
```

By simply setting the body display to 'none' you don't have to worry about a flash of the browser scrolling to the top of the page before it is unloaded and the scroll position will automatically be reset to 0.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Chrome when going "back" to a page, or "refreshing" a page.