# Automatic scroll by browsers

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Here is my code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLdH5/)

```
var curSlot = 9;
var numOfSlot = 10;

function newDivs() {
    $("body").append("<div class = 'imgBox'></div>");
}
for (var i = 0; i < numOfSlot; i++) {
    newDivs();
}
$(".imgBox").height(window.innerHeight);
scrollTo(0, innerHeight * curSlot);
```

Why the window always after load, scroll on a random element and not stay on scrolling position??? In jsFiddle it works fine but in google chrome and mozzila (and maybe in other browser i don´t now) it dosn´t work.

Comment: What value is innerHeight supposed to have in the bottommost line?

Comment: Yes, but that is not the same. Then you should write out `window.innerHeight` explicitly, just like in the line above.

Comment: I think is it the same but Ok. But the problem is still unresolved :(

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome and other modern browsers remember last scroll of document, so if i move with scrollbar and several refresh page, the scrollbar is still on the same position. Here is the same question: [Chrome remembers scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239520/chrome-remembers-scroll-position), but now works only solution via `setInterval(scrollFunction,0)...` by  [bob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16241083/2158562).