# jQuery scrollTop(val) not working on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this current and simple html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            margin:0;
            height:5321px;
            width:7000px;
        }
        .contenedor-mapa {
            height:5321px;
            width:7000px;           
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('body').scrollTop($('body').height()/2);
            $('body').scrollLeft($('body').width()/2);
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor-mapa"> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was working on a jquery script to make the scroll center automatically and It was driving me crazy as it seemed nothing was working and cound't see any reason why.

To my surprise I translated the code to a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qw326opb/2/) and it was working as expected. so after some tests it looks like the script only works after opening the html on a new window or browser tab, first time and just first time. After that if I refresh (F5 or Ctrl+F5) the script does not work again as I think it should.

I tried all I could think of as changing `$(document).ready(function() {});` for `( window ).on( "load", function() {});` but still the same. And I can`t keep working if everytime I need to refresh to check new code I have to keep opening the html on new tabs.

The html is not under any IDE, just an archive on a folder, but I even tried to create a new website in visual studio, I run this html aand I had the same problem.

Maybe I am missing something very simple but any help would be greatly apreciated

**EDITED**: If you try to replicate the problem, load the page, MOVE the scroll and refresh. The scroll does not center again...at least for me.

Comment: I did what you just tried with putting it in a simple HTML and opening it, and it centered it on the first open, without refreshing. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: So your fiddle works but your page doesn't? There is obviously something different about your page then. With a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) no one can solve this but you.

Comment: Can also not reproduce with the HTML above. It works for every opening or refresh.

Comment: Lixus. Once it loads move the scroll and then refresh the page. I expect the scroll to move to be centered again

Comment: Is this only a google chrome problem? If so this is a duplicate of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239520/chrome-remembers-scroll-position I could reproduce the problem but only if you scroll around and only tested in google chrome

Comment: Why dont you test if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/flosommerfeld/qw326opb/4/) does work. In some browsers the scroll methods wont work anyway..

Comment: Have you tried using `$('body, html').scrollTop(...);`?  Without the `html` in there also, I get unexpected results.

Comment: Fantastic Flosommerfed Your solution worked. Write it down and I'll give You the credit. Ty caramba. the solution with 19 upvotes in your link worked, but just on chrome. No idea why 3 people voted to close this question as "off-topic"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are two ways to go around such a problem

---

**1.** Way - Using the animate() method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ($('body').height() / 2) }, 0);
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollLeft: ($('body').width() / 2) }, 0);
});
```

---

**2.** Way - Using 'html' instead of 'body'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html').scrollTop($('html').height()/2);
  $('html').scrollLeft($('html').width()/2);
});
```

Comment: Note: your code didn't work in firefox, this will however

Comment: Ty again. very much apreciated

Answer (score -1):

Getting the real document dimesnions can be complicated in some cases or browsers. You could verify if it returns the proper value.:

```
console.log($('body').width());
console.log($('body').height());
```

Maybe it returns 0 or null in your case. In this case you could try to use this plugin [jQuery.documentSize](https://github.com/hashchange/jquery.documentsize). It should return proper value in all the scenarios.

Comment: Probably because it's just an *idea*, it's not an *answer*.  An answer would be complete, and would have the code to correct the problem.  This is more troubleshooting tips, which belongs in a comment, not an answer.