# Where does the browser store scrollTop information when element is set to display: none?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am using Polymer and i have a paper-dialog in which i have a scrollable div. When i close the dialog the scrollTop property is 0, but when i reopen it the value returns to what it was before closing. I want to reset the scroll to 0, so when it is opened again it starts at the beginning.

Comment: Why don't you just set `scrollTop` to 0 after "opening"?

Comment: Because you can see the scrolling that way. It started as i want to fix this, but ended in where does the browser store that info. Now i just want to know that.

Comment: There's an answer about disabling this "feature" in Chrome and Firefox here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239520/chrome-remembers-scroll-position maybe that will help.

Comment: it's basically the same thing that scrolls the page to a point after you refresh it, it's meant to help users.. if you want to prevent this you need to reset the scrollTop yourself.. also I think that it's also reset if the content completely changes (you clear the contents when you exist and add them back in)